# Multiple Propset Guid Mapped to a Category

Tags: powershell, fast-search, properties, managed-property, fast-for-sharepoint

I'm working in a powershell scrip for F4SP 2010 server that reads lines from a .csv file and creates the mappings between managed properties a crawled properties.

I don't have much problem, just a question.

I found that categories can have multiple Guids mapped to them, I wanted to retrieve the Guid associated to a category, so I could be more specific in the crawled property search, without depending on Guid from the category, but I found that from the name of the category I cannot get a Guid.

The primary purpose of getting it is that, if I do not find a crawled property with Guid and Name specified in the .csv, I create a new one using `New-FASTSearchMetadataCrawledProperty`, for what I need the propset Id.

**Do anyone knows why a category has multiple Guids?**

Comment: Could you explain what you mean by a category? Usually property sets and crawled property categories are spoken of as one and the same.

Comment: Well I'm too new, and probably I don't know how to explain exactly, but, a crawled property is created with a Name, a PropsetId and a Variant Type, the object crawled property has a property called CategoryName this, CategoryName is the name of a Category...

Comment: Ok, and that CategoryName corresponds to the guid in Propset. There are many crawled properties in one category/property set. So a category (or propertyset) will have many crawled properties mapped to it. The identifier for a crawled property is: name/id+varianttype+category(propset). When creating a new crawled property manually you can create it in either of the pre-existing categories(propertysets) or create a new category with a guid of your own choosing. Hope this clarifies it a bit.

Comment: Yes, but, I found a CategoryName can be mapped to several propsetIds, so what I'm asking is, why this is like this? :)

Comment: Ahh.. yes.. .you can indeed use the same name on several categories as it's a display name. The guid is what is used when linking it to crawled properties. Never thought of that. Same goes for crawled properties. You can use the same name for different propertysets and varianttypes. Which category name do you have a duplicate for?

Comment: For example Basic, it has 4 different prosetIds.

Comment: You are right indeed. Never noticed. If you try to create a new category you cannot use the same Name and different propset guid. I see from the internal implementation that the propsets are a collection on the category. I see SharePoint has 3 mappings and Office has two. And I have no idea why this is.