# In Sharepoint 2010, What does the CrawledProperty's PropSet Member Represent?

Tags: search, enterprise-search

Can someone explain what the PropSet member attribute of the CrawledProperty class is in Sharepoint Server Search?

The below MSDN link gives me no clue as to what it is, and I am in the process of creating a CrawledProperty programatically.  My first thought is, it's a unique identifier, but there is no way to tell based on the documentation.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.search.extended.administration.schema.crawledproperty.propset(v=office.14).aspx

Comment: The Guid belongs to the category, read the comments here: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/27817/multiple-propset-guid-mapped-to-a-category